# Can't open the Finder page for my iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, finder

I'm trying to back up my iPhone before enrolling in the Beta program, but when I enter the Finder page for my iPhone, it doesn't stop loading. I used to be able to open this menu up just fine, but now I can't.[image].

Comment: Did you restart both your Mac and your phone already?

Comment: I thought It had shut down previously when it died. Turns out it didn't and I just had to actually restart.